# No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl and No such algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I am trying to create a cipher in order to encode an AES key that I have created. I had read in a public key from a file that I stored the public key in and converted it from bytes to a public key object. When I try to initilize the cipher using this public key, I get the error "No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl" at       `cipherAES.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, DecodedPublicKey);`

So when I create a RSA 2048 key generator object to get the provider, which is the specifications I used in order to create the previous key in another program, I get the error "No such algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding" at `Cipher cipherAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", kpgenProv.getName());`

I need to use the transformation AES/GCM/NoPadding, and the provider that is being given from the .getProvider seems to be right, which is SunRsaSign. Does anyone have any insight into this problem? It recognizes the transformation fine when there is no provider, but rejects it when there is a provider.

````
      String pubAlgo = publicKeyScanner.nextLine(); // not used
      String PublicKey = publicKeyScanner.nextLine(); // this will stop when it hits a newline and the encoded key may have the newline char value causing the private key to be piecemeal
      byte[] decodedPublicKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(PublicKey);
      KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); // or "EC" or whatever
      PublicKey DecodedPublicKey = kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedPublicKey));
      publicKeyScanner.close();
      System.out.println(DecodedPublicKey.toString());
    
      KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
      keyGen.init(128); // for example
      SecretKey AESKey = keyGen.generateKey();

      KeyPairGenerator kpgen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
      kpgen.initialize(2048);
      Provider kpgenProv = kpgen.getProvider();
      System.out.println(kpgenProv.getName());
      Cipher cipherAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", kpgenProv.getName());
      cipherAES.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, DecodedPublicKey);
      byte[] AESKEYBYTES = AESKey.getEncoded();```
````

Comment: I found that adding transformation as "RSA" made everything work, removing the provider. This removes the transformation AES/GCM though, is this still a valid way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java JDK's usually are delivered with some security providers that are responsible for cryptographic operations. Due to historical reasons they didn't got combined/bundled but exist beneath each other. If you choose an algorithm by instantiating Java will find out which provider is "responsible" for this algorithm and takes him.

On the other hand - if you like to use a specific provider you can name the provider during instantiation (that's what you are doing with the second parameter "kpgenProv.getName":

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", kpgenProv.getName())
```

As you see in my simple program there are two **different** provider for "RSA" and "AES/GCM/NoPadding" but when forcing a specific provider you receive a "no-installed-provider-supports..." exception.

So usually you leave out the provider name and let Java choose for the "best" provider for this algorithm.

output on my system (OpenJDK11):

```
Get security provider
provider for RSA encryption: SunRsaSign version 11
provider for AES/GCM/NoPadding: SunJCE version 11
```

code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        System.out.println("Get security provider");

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        System.out.println("provider for RSA encryption: " + kf.getProvider());

        Cipher cipherAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        System.out.println("provider for AES/GCM/NoPadding: " + cipherAES.getProvider());
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, however, the problem I get when I do not give it a provider and leave it as         Cipher cipherAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding"); is that when I go to use cipherAES.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, DecodedPublicKey), it complains that I don't have the correct provider installed, No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl, do I need to import something?

Comment: I am creating the keys from bytes, but the key is not null, so i don't think that's a problem. When i change the AES/GCM/NoPadding to RSA, it suddenly works without any errors, but I still want the transformation to be AES-GCM, so I don't think that's a problem. Could this possibly a be a problem with my IDE I am using?

Comment: My answer is for the "no provider" part of your problem. Do you try to run a **hybrid encryption**? Then you need to encrypt the (randomly) generated AES GCM key with a RSA encryption algorithm. Your program has the issue that the input for the AES GCM-cipher is the public key - this does not work. Search for "java aes gcm rsa hybrid encryption" and you will find a lot of examples.

Comment: Ok, will do! Thanks for the help!